# Why for iOS 10 and above we must assign your delegate BEFORE your app finishes launching?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In the doc at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client then say

> for devices running iOS 10 and above, you must assign your delegate
>   object to the UNUserNotificationCenter object to receive display
>   notifications, and the FIRMessaging object to receive data messages,
>   before your app finishes launching. For example, in an iOS app, you
>   must assign it in the applicationWillFinishLaunching: or
>   applicationDidFinishLaunching: method.

But why in iOS 10 we must set this **BEFORE** app finishes launching (and this only for iOS 10+) ?

Comment: it's required because of your deviceToken register in firebase.so before calling below method it's must required.- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging )messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(NSString )fcmToken {
    NSLog(@"FCM registration token: %@", fcmToken);

Comment: but why on iOS 10 and not on iOS 9?